# The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<XXX.Models.Domain>.Add(XXX.Models.Domain)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to first search the domain ids from a particular table based on tenant and then for the domain id I am looking for domain names in another table and adding in  a list. I am getting an error on adding the domain object in my list. My code is as shown below:

```
public IEnumerable<Domain> GetAllByTenant(Guid tenantId)
    {
        List<Domain> domains = null;
        var ids = _applicationDbContext.TenantDomainMap.Where(x => x.TenantId == tenantId).Select(x => x.DomainId);

        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            var domain = _applicationDbContext.Domain.Where(x => x.DomainId == id);
            domains.Add(domain);

        }
        return domains;
    }
```

I am getting following errors at domains.Add(domain):
1. The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(XXX.Models.Domain)' has some invalid arguments
2. cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'XXX.Models.Domain'

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Where` method always returns an `IQueryable` because it has no way of knowing how many items matched your predicate.

There are 4 potential methods you can add after the `Where` call to resolve this problem.

**Single**:
This method expects only one match and it will throw an exception if more than one match was found or if no matches were found.

```
 var domain = _applicationDbContext.Domain.Where(x => x.DomainId == id).Single();
```

**SingleOrDefault**:
This method is the same as `Single` except that it will return the results of default(T), where T is your type, when no results are found; this is usually null.

```
 var domain = _applicationDbContext.Domain.Where(x => x.DomainId == id).SingleOrDefault();
```

**First**:
This method will return the first item in the list and will only throw an exception if no matches were found.

```
 var domain = _applicationDbContext.Domain.Where(x => x.DomainId == id).First();
```

**FirstOrDefault**:
This method unlike `First` will not throw an exception on no matches, instead it works just like `SingleOrDefault` and will return the type's default value.

```
 var domain = _applicationDbContext.Domain.Where(x => x.DomainId == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Given that you are doing a search on an Id, `Single` is probably the correct choice, though depending on your saving logic `SingleOrDefault` may be needed.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I got it now. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Rash Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `.FirstOrDefault();` to ensure only return the first match returned from the `Where`.

```
foreach (var id in ids)
{
      var domain = _applicationDbContext.Domain.Where(x => x.DomainId == id).FirstOrDefault();
      domains.Add(domain);   
}
```

`Where` returns type `IEnumerable` and you need to add a single `Domain` type to your list, for each.